# Looping through a json object to parse a horizontal row using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm just a bit stuck on how to approach this situation.

I go this JSON that looks like this

```
[
{
    "date":"oct10",
    "number_x": "100",
    "number_y": "200",
    "number_z": "300"
},
{
    "date":"oct11",
    "number_x": "300",
    "number_y": "600",
    "number_z": "200"
},
{
    "date":"oct13",
    "number_x": "200",
    "number_y": "660",
    "number_z": "230"
}
]
```

I'm trying to achieve an output similar to this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>"date":"oct10"</td>
        <td>"date":"oct11"</td>
        <td>"date":"oct12"</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>"number_x": "100",</td>
        <td>"number_x": "300",</td>
        <td>"number_x": "200",</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>"number_y": "200",</td>
        <td>"number_y": "600",</td>
        <td>"number_y": "660",</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>"number_z": "300",</td>
        <td>"number_z": "200",</td>
        <td>"number_z": "230",</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help or starting point would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for reading.

Comment: Are you the one who build the JSON ? If yes, can you show us how you build it ?

Comment: The use of  `json_decode` which transforms your json into a php array and 4 simple `for-loops` can probably solve your problem

Comment: @ThinkTank no I'm not building the json response, it's an API call.

Comment: @Silencio yes I've already done the json_decode. It's beyond that I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will parse the `json` string, then build some extra arrays in order to pivot the data.

It will output as desired.

```
$jsonStr = '[
{
    "date":"oct10",
    "number_x": "100",
    "number_y": "200",
    "number_z": "300"
},
{
    "date":"oct11",
    "number_x": "300",
    "number_y": "600",
    "number_z": "200"
},
{
    "date":"oct13",
    "number_x": "200",
    "number_y": "660",
    "number_z": "230"
}
]';

$obj = json_decode($jsonStr);

foreach($obj as $row){
    $date[] = $row->date;
    $x[] = $row->number_x;
    $y[] = $row->number_y;
    $z[] = $row->number_z;

}

print '<table>' . 
    '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>Date: ',$date) . '</td></tr>' . 
    '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>Number X : ',$x) . '</td></tr>' . 
    '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>Number Y : ',$y) . '</td></tr>' . 
    '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>Number X : ',$z) . '</td></tr>' . 
    '</table>';
```